# Javascript adding date

Tags: javascript

i have been given this code and told to add in the setup method to add the 4 fish owners.

```
Controller.prototype.setup = function () {
'use strict';
var theAquarium;
theAquarium = new Aquarium();
```

i have to add the following information 
to add for each owner:

```
PHK    Phil         Key     8/05/1980
RUT    Russel       Turia   16/02/1984
TAN    Tariana      Norman  30/11/1987
JOG    John         Goff    12/12/1982
```

i tried adding it like this but it isn't working

```
Controller.prototype.setup = function () {
'use strict';
var theAquarium;
theAquarium = new Aquarium();
theAquarium.addFishOwner( 'PHK' , 'Phil' , 'Key' , setFullYear(8/05/1980));
theAquarium.addFishOwner( 'RUT' , 'Russel' , 'Turia' , setFullYear(16/02/1984));
theAquarium.addFishOwner( 'TAN' , 'Tariana' , 'Norman' , setFullYear(30/11/1987));
theAquarium.addFishOwner( 'JOG' , 'John' , 'Goff' , setFullYear(12/12/1982));
```

please help

Comment: Either no JS: `'Key' , "8/05/1980")` OR if you need a date - `'Key' , new Date("8/05/1980")` unless there is a built-in setFullYear in your framework which you did not tell us

Answer (score 1):

Try this, let me know if I understand what you are asking

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var fisherman1 = {
    name: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    DOB: '8/05/1980'
  };

  var fisherman2 = {
    name: "John1",
    lastName: "Al",
    DOB: '8/05/1980'
  };

  var fisherman3 = {
    name: "Alan",
    lastName: "123",
    DOB: '8/05/1980'
  };

  var fisherman4 = {
    name: "Jim",
    lastName: "A",
    DOB: '8/05/1980'
  };


  var array1 = new Array(4);

  array1.push(fisherman1);

  array1.push(fisherman2);

  array1.push(fisherman3);

  array1.push(fisherman4);


  for (x = 0; x < array1.length; x++) {
    $("div").append(x + ":" + array1.pop(0).name + ".");
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d"></div>
```